# Browser doesn't cache resources

Tags: browser, firebug, cache-control

I checked my site with Firebug: Each time I reload the page,  all resources are loaded again. (I am NOT by clicking "reload" in the browser, but using a link on the homepage leading to the homepage)

Just to pick an example: **base.css** gives a "200 ok" status each time I load the page.

```
The response header says: 
Cache-Control   max-age=5184000, private
Last-Modified   10 Feb 2012 20:00:00 GMT
```

From all that I have read upto now, this should be sufficient to make the browser cache this file.

I checked this with two different versions of Firefox on two different machines - but with the same result.

What is missing to make the browser cache the file?

confusingly enough, with about:cache, I can see that the browser has put base.css into its disk-cache and increments the fetch count every time I reload the page. Is firebug playing a prank on me?

Comment: You may want to post a sample URL that the browser pulls in. Sometimes frameworks add cache buster params to the URL to skip caching.

Comment: @DmitryB The site is [www.yogasearch.de](http://www.yogasearch.de)

Answer (score 0):

Yogi, I attached the screen shot (see below or click this URL https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT0gU.png) of what I see in the browser. There is some caching going of resources (like widget76.css) but the base.css is not cached as you have said.

There are a couple of things that I observed:

1. Base CSS file is marked Cache-Control: private. I know it's for proxies, but never the less.
2. Base CSS is not explicitly included in the HTML header, but is being imported from another css file (probably not relevant).
3. widget76.css has an "If-Modified-Since" header http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html which allows for efficient caching strategy. Can't see in the image but this is what the request headers have:

   If-Modified-Since  :     Wed, 01 Feb 2012 12:31:58 GMT

   Cache-Control  : max-age=0

So all in all I think it's the missing If-Modified-Since header that makes the difference.

[image: Firefox Net tab of CSS resources]

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my inital problem is fairly trivial: 
In default-mode of firebugs network-analysis "BFCache Answers" are enabled. The effect is that requests to the cache are shown in the list and this gives the impression that they were coming from the server.

Thanks for the help, DmitryB!